# Tag synonym needed for Custom-Event

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-overflow

These tags should be synonymized:

[custom-event](/questions/tagged/custom-event) should either be synonymized to [custom-events](/questions/tagged/custom-events), or vice versa.

Comment: Both should be burninated imo